# Sum only positive elements of a vector CUDA/THRUST

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, thrust, gpu

I'd like to use Thrust (as most of my method is implemented using thrust data types) or C CUDA if necessary to sum only the positive floating point elements of a vector. The data is not initially sorted. My initial stab was very bad: basically, copy off the vector, sort it, find the zero crossing by passing it to a kernel which compares sequential pair-wise values and writes those that match the zero crossing. Basically after sorting (which I do with Thrust)...

```
int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
if (i < n - 1) {
  float a = vector[i];
  float b = vector[i + 1];
  if (a >= 0.0 && b < 0.0)
    answer = i + 1;
}
```

This is really dumb witted, lots of threads match the conditional, way too many reads, branch divergences, etc. So, it totally fails, each call will give different results on the same data, etc.

I have yet to find a good way to implement this in Thrust, which is what I would prefer. After sorting I don't know how to find the zero crossing. Any advice on a jumping off point here? An actually working simple CUDA C implementation would be just fine too.

Comment: Why is sorting necessary? Do you actually need the data to be ordered? Also, what's with weird pointer usage in that kernel snippet? What is the extra level of pointer indirection intended to achieve?

Comment: The pointer indirection isn't intended to achieve anything, I just wrote it quickly, but the question has nothing to do with it. I will update it so it doesn't cause confusion. Sorting I assumed would be beneficial since I could then so a simple reduction in the first N elements of the vector. It appears thrust::transform_reduce, answered below (user ngimel), solves my issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To sum only positive values, you do not need to sort your initial values, use 
thrust::transform_reduce:

```
template<typename T>
struct positive_value : public thrust::unary_function<T,T>
{
   __host__ __device__ T operator()(const T &x) const
   {
     return x < T(0) ? 0  : x;
   }
};

float result = thrust::transform_reduce(data.begin(), data.end(),
                                    positive_value<float>(),
                                    0,
                                    thrust::plus<float>());
```